# OP2177 opamp with single supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, single-supply-op-amp, negative-voltage

Does anyone know if I can use "**OP2177**" with a **single supply** without a negative voltage on V- ?

Comment: What are you using it for? You'll get better answers if you can give some more information.

Comment: You can, in general, do this, but be careful about the input/output voltage swings, and what voltage you use as the "ground reference" in your opamp circuits. Read up on rail splitting and virtual ground circuits to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can certainly use it in a single supply configuration, it all depends on your needs.

Given it's not a rail-to-rail op-amp, neither in input or output, if your voltage input is close to 0V and requires some precision, you will most likely have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can, the opamp is only interested in the difference between the `V-` and `V+` pins, this has to be less than or equal to 36 V.

Depending on what you're using the opamp for, you will probably want to offset your signal from 0 V.